# Using class "col" and "col-3" together

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm using the class "col" to create 7 equal columns and when responsive I would like to have two rows. One with 4 columns and the other with 3.
Here's my code

```
<div class="row mt-20">
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/cegh.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/usp.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/butanta.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/fapesp.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/inct.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3">
            <img src="assets/img/analitica.png" width="80%">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-3 mb-5">
            <img src="assets/img/abcam.png" width="80%">
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I do this, I got the two rows even when not responsive and not the 7 that I wanted.

Comment: col is use for all screen and col-sm-* is use for small screen and so on, for more information visit https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: can you describe your expected output

Comment: Using a desktop should appear 7 columns in one row and using a mobile should appear 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have elements using a size of `3` columns (i.e 4 columns on each row) when screen size is **XS**, and have equal width columns when the size of the screen is greater or equal to some breakpoint (in this example I will use **SM**). This can be approached with the conjunction of classes `col-3 col-{breakpoint}` as is shown on the next example for `breakpoint = SM` (margin top is added for good looking only):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-sm mt-1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" width="80%">
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you!